# Error in retrieving remote objects

Tags: visualforce, javascript, query, remote-objects

You can copy and paste my code easily into your dev console to debug this. I'm trying to get a list of users from a remote object query. After typing a value in the input box, click outside the box and you get this error.

> Invalid criteria specified for retrieval. ValidationError [code=11, message=Data does not match any schemas from "oneOf", path=/where, schemaKey=null]

I'm pretty sure I followed the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm) correctly.

```
<apex:page >

    <!-- Remote Objects definition to set accessible sObjects and fields -->
    <apex:remoteObjects >

        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="User" fields="Id, FirstName, LastName, Email"/>

    </apex:remoteObjects>  

    <input type="text" name="txt" onchange="fetchUsers(this.value)" />


    <h1>List of users</h1>

    <ul id="userList">
    </ul>

        <!-- JavaScript to make Remote Objects calls -->
    <script>
        function fetchUsers(string){
            // Create a new Remote Object
            var u = new SObjectModel.User();

            // Use the Remote Object to query for 10 user records


            var criteria = { where: {
                FirstName: {like: string.split(' ')[0]},
                LastName:  {like: string.split(' ')[1]}
            },
            orderby: [ {LastName: 'ASC'}, {FirstName: 'ASC'} ],
            limit: 10 
            };

            console.log(criteria);

            u.retrieve(criteria, function(error, results, event){
                if(error) {
                    alert(error.message);
                }
                else{
                    var ul = document.getElementById("userList");
                    results.forEach(function(record) {
                        var uText = record.get("Id");
                        uText += " -- ";
                        uText += record.get("FirstName");
                        uText += " -- ";
                        uText += record.get("LastName");
                        uText += " -- ";
                        uText += record.get("Email");

                        var li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uText));
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                    });
                };

            });
        };
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing with your model and my observation is that the query does not seem to like it (ha) when you use a `like` clause which does not include a wildcard. I tried with just `FirstName`, just `LastName`, and with both, and no matter what, any time I included a `like` clause which did not contain a wildcard, it blew up with the same error you described. This leads me to conclude:

> You cannot retrieve records with `Remote Objects` using a `like` clause that does not contain a wildcard character (`%` or `_`).

I don't have a reference for that, it's just my observation.

The following worked for me just fine. I added a loop to clear out previous results and tightened things up marginally.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="User" fields="Id, FirstName, LastName, Email"/>
    </apex:remoteObjects>  
    <input type="text" name="txt" id="user_search" />
    <h1>List of users</h1>
    <ul id="userList"></ul>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("user_search").addEventListener("change", function () {
        var u = new SObjectModel.User(),
            elements = this.value.split(" "),
            first = (elements[0] || "") + "%",
            last = (elements[1] || "") + "%",
            criteria = {
                where: {
                    FirstName: {like: first},
                    LastName:  {like: last}
                },
                orderby: [ {LastName: "ASC"}, {FirstName: "ASC"} ],
                limit: 10 
            };
        u.retrieve(criteria, function(error, results, event){
            if(error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }
            else{
                console.debug(results);
                var ul = document.getElementById("userList");
                while (ul.firstChild) { ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild); }
                results.forEach(function(record) {
                    var uText = record.get("Id");
                    uText += " -- ";
                    uText += record.get("FirstName");
                    uText += " -- ";
                    uText += record.get("LastName");
                    uText += " -- ";
                    uText += record.get("Email");

                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uText));
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                });
            };

        });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I wish the docs said that. I guess it's implied from the docs saying " As with SOQL, use “%” as a wildcard character."

Comment: But in SOQL, the wildcard is not required. Ah well.