# Getting only phone fields name of a particular object

Tags: apex, visualforce, schema

Getting only phone fields name of a particular object.
I am using Js remoting technique in my visualforce page. How to get only the fields that are of type Phone?

Comment: [sobject](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009024IAA) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the fields of a certain object, for instance, Account, then use the Schema namespace:

```
SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> accountFields = accountType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Afterwards, just iterate through the `SObjectFields` and use the `getType()` method to filter them. Check up the documentation here.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_simple.htm?search_text=remote%20object), like as follows: [Error in retrieving remote objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146796/error-in-retrieving-remote-objects)

The Remote Objects allow us to specify fields to be retrieved and do not require any odd service-side implementation:

```
<apex:remoteObjects >

    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="User" fields="Id, FirstName, LastName, Email"/>

</apex:remoteObjects>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get field type from object field use following code

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> objectMap =Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
```

for( string obj : objectMap.keySet()){

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> objFieldMap = objectMap.get(obj).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(string field : objFieldMap.keySet()){

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = objFieldMap.get(field).getDescribe();          
    system.debug('*********************'+dfr.getType());        
}
```

}

now you can get a which type of you want

Thank you,
Amol Salve
Salesforce Developer